# What does 'intimated' mean in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, psychology, philosophy

> As we shall see, when satisfaction is invoked in Othello, and by
> Othello himself, what is being sought is proof and revenge, knowledge
> and retaliation, certainty and redress. And what is more than
> intimated, as I want to show, is just how inextricable these things
> can be.

This is a philosophic, psychoanalytic text. What does 'intimated' mean in the above passage?

I have searched in different dictionaries and I can find many meaning the problem is that I cannot say which meaning is the closest in this context

Does it mean more than what has been said, more than just how inextricable can these things be? If "intimated" here means explained or shown, then what is that "more" doing in the sentence?

Answer (score 0):

> "[Intimated](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/intimated)" - indicated or made known indirectly; hinted at; implied.

The meaning of "intimated" is the *opposite* of "shared expressly," what another here said it means.

Now, it is true that the meaning "shared expressly" may be inferred from the citation, but only from the entire phrase "more than intimated," meaning "went beyond just hinting at or implying." The entire phrase "more than intimated" may *intimate* (i.e., *hint at* or *imply*) the meaning "shared expressly," but "intimated" itself doesn't mean "shared expressly" but means the opposite of "shared expressly."

It'd be like if the phrase "not turned off" appeared in some reading of yours, you asked the meaning of "off" in that phrase, and someone answered, "'Off' here means 'on.'" That wouldn't be true, tough. Only the entire phrase "not turned off" may be inferred as meaning "on," not the word "off," which by itself means the exact opposite of "on."